# Using Matlab poctave function under 3 Hz

Tags: matlab, fourier

I would like to get the Fourier transform of my data from 0,5 to 80 Hz at every 1/3 octave.

I tried using Matlab poctave function but that one is only working over 3 Hz.

My question is there a way to make the poctave function work under 3 Hz or there is another way for me to get the Fourier transform of my data.

Thank you for your help in advance and sorry if I was not clear enough!

Comment: you want a Fourier transform of discrete data  – a discrete Fourier transform. Hm. Can't really be *that* hard searching for that, but oh, well, is probably an early Matlab problem for you: The `fft` function is your friend.

Comment: A DFT provides you linearly spaced frequency bins given data sampled at a constant sampling rate, and the number of bins is limited by the number of samples. Octaves are not linear, and so the octave below 3 Hz might not include any sensible frequency bins aside from DC. Can you tell us your DFT size and sample rate?

Comment: I thought about the fft function but thought there is anotherway where i don't have to average out myself. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: My sample rate is 160 Hz and the (if I understand correctly the DFT size is the number of data points I have) DFT size is 30000

Comment: You'll need to gather data for 6 seconds: 0.5 Hz and 3 bins/octave suggests  this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`poctave`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/poctave.html) isn't a transform, it's a bank of filters.

I'm not sure why the artificial lower limit of 3 Hz exists.<sup>1</sup> But you could try lying to it — tell it your sample rate is 160 Hz × 300 = 48 kHz, and then divide the frequency results by 300. That'll get you down to 0.01 Hz.

---

<sup>1</sup> I can see that the limit of \$F_s\frac{3}{48000}\$ might be related to the maximum order of the filters used internally, but I don't see why there's an *absolute* limit of 3 Hz.